# How can I render an event to whole cell in full calendar js?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

is  there some sort of property that lets me do this?
I tried eventRender but dont know how to do it.
here is my calender now: 
[image]

I want the period to cover the whole day cell like [image]

Comment: Please provide more information what you need. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: The image you showed on top doesn't seems to be a day view. Instead its a month view. This means you want [recurring](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events) events.

Comment: yes. that is month .. i want that period 8 to have a bg-color which cover all the cell like second one@khan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You may need a [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events).

```
events: [
  {
    "title":"Lorem Ipsum",
    "start":"2019-04-16",
    "end":"2019-04-16",
    "rendering": "background",
    "color":"red"
  },
]
```

or if you want to have events with both types of rendering you can do so like.

If i understand your question well, Yes you can

```
 events:[
           {
              "title": "event 5",
              "start": "2019-04-24T10:00:00",
              "end": "2019-04-24T13:00:00",
            },
            {
              "title": "event 2",
              "start": "2019-04-24T14:00:00",
              "end": "2019-04-24T15:00:00",
              "backgroundColor": "red"
            },
            {
              "start": "2019-04-24T12:00:00",
              "end": "2019-04-24T16:00:00",
              "rendering": "background"
            },
          ],
```

Comment: its working.. but few  more question.. is it possible to render an event like default but one event on rendering? .. I mean I only need one event to be rendered on background its on a loop how can i set redering to normal way what is the value.. and is it possible to render one event on background and another events top of it as default render.. Thanks

Comment: If i understand your question well, Yes you can. I update my answer.